# Wordpress install within Laravel application - permalinks not working

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

I wish to have a Wordpress blog running alongside a Laravel install.

In the root directory I have the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Within the public directory I've added a `blog` directory and installed an existing Wordpress site.

The Wordpress .htaccess file is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

I can visit existing urls within my Laravel application fine.

I can browse the `/blog` url and the Wordpress blog is displayed.

If I disable Wordpress pretty urls I can visit all pages within the Wordpress blog without issue.

**The issue**

When enabling a custom permalink structure within Wordpress none of the inner pages work.

For example, `/blog/some-slug` doesn't load, ignores Wordpress and is incorrectly handled by Laravel.

I've read loads of similar Stackoverflow isues and they all suggest adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
```

to the default Laravel .htaccess file at `public/.htaccess`. This however appears to have no effect.

Comment: Those permalinks/slugs are overridden by Laravel's routing. You could write the route for wordpress in Laravel, but why don't you install wordpress somewhere else?

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have it installed using the same folder structrure as I'm moving servers. I gather it's a htaccess issue though.

Comment: It's not really. Your htaccess points to Laravel's index.php, **unless** the file or directory really exists on the server (hence /blog working as it is a real folder). However the permalinks/slugs come from the database, and are virtual paths/routes and that is where Laravel takes precedence.

Comment: That's true, which is why the common solutions I've tried don't work. Adding ````RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/```` to my htaccess should be skipping any urls that start with "blog".